# adb connection problem on Kubuntu 13.04 x64

Tags: adb, linux

I'm facing a problem with ABD connection under Kubuntu 13.04 x64. Every time I try to push/pull/shell ls the adb disconnects from device. I tried the following solutions:

1. Added device ID into .android/adb_usb.ini but nothing helped
2. Added new udev rule and also nothing helped
3. Flashed the ROM and nothing helped
4. I re-installed my Kubuntu 13.04 x64

Some notes :

- USB Debugging activated
- Device is Prestigio PMP5080BRU (Rooted) - Android Gingerbread 2.3.1
- I'm using the latest Android SDK available on official web site
- The ADB works very well on Windows 7 x64
- Even when ADB disconnects, I still can see device via **lsusb**
  command
- ia32-libs already installed on the system
- jdk and jre installed on the system and works as expected
- Paths configured and working properly
- ADB works as expected with my Samsung Galaxy S II (Jelly Bean 4.1.2 -
  Stock)

dmesg :

```
[ 5571.640498] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 5571.657013] usb 3-2: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 bulk endpoint 0x83 has invalid maxpacket 64
[ 5571.657426] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bb4, idProduct=0c02
[ 5571.657433] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5571.657436] usb 3-2: Product: rk2918
[ 5571.657439] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: RockChip
[ 5571.657442] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[ 5571.664067] scsi13 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[ 5572.659163] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     PMP5080B                  0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 5572.659453] scsi 13:0:0:1: Direct-Access     PMP5080B                  0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 5572.661211] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 5572.661525] sd 13:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 5572.662492] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 5572.662947] sd 13:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Any one got an idea?
Regards,,,

Comment: Any hints in your Kubuntu's `dmesg` output?

Comment: I added dmesg to the question... By the way, I changed the USB cable, but still same result.

Comment: That's just the last lines. Add the lines, that come up when you connect the device and you try `adb shell`. `dmesg >f1` connect+adb `dmesg >f2` `f2 -= f1`.

Comment: I got no more lines actually after connect the device, after adb shell push/pull/ls it disconnects

Comment: It's connecting the device as 2 scsi disks then? Can you change the usb mode to something else in your Prestigio?

Comment: Only turn On/Off USB Storage

Comment: Have you tried it with that option set to `off`?

Comment: I tried with both, nothing helped actually.

Comment: Hi, i'm facing the same problem, did you managed to connect the device? On my 12-04 x64 kubuntu I've managed to connect the device (Prestigio PER5274B) by adding this line: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="2207", MODE="0666"` to `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`. I've got the number 2207 from lspci command (vendorId). However this approach is not working for me in 13-04, but maybe it'll be working for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with a Rockchip device.  Short `adb shell` commands worked, but ones with multi-line output just disconnected randomly, sometimes before producing any output.

On plugging the device in, the kernel syslogged the following:

```
Dec 30 20:38:03 icebox kernel: [ 1153.016178] usb 9-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Dec 30 20:38:03 icebox kernel: [ 1153.032476] usb 9-1.1: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 bulk endpoint 0x81 has invalid maxpacket 64
Dec 30 20:38:03 icebox kernel: [ 1153.038276] usb 9-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=2207, idProduct=0006
Dec 30 20:38:03 icebox kernel: [ 1153.038281] usb 9-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
Dec 30 20:38:03 icebox kernel: [ 1153.038284] usb 9-1.1: Product: rk30sdk
Dec 30 20:38:03 icebox kernel: [ 1153.038287] usb 9-1.1: Manufacturer: rockchip
Dec 30 20:38:03 icebox kernel: [ 1153.038290] usb 9-1.1: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
Dec 30 20:38:03 icebox colord: Device added: sysfs-rockchip-rk30sdk
```

Out of desperation I moved the device from a USB3 socket on my Linux box to a USB2 socket, as follows

```
Dec 30 20:45:03 icebox kernel: [ 1572.844024] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
Dec 30 20:45:03 icebox kernel: [ 1572.976394] usb 1-3: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 bulk endpoint 0x81 has invalid maxpacket 64
Dec 30 20:45:03 icebox kernel: [ 1572.976889] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=2207, idProduct=0006
Dec 30 20:45:03 icebox kernel: [ 1572.976893] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
Dec 30 20:45:03 icebox kernel: [ 1572.976896] usb 1-3: Product: rk30sdk
Dec 30 20:45:03 icebox kernel: [ 1572.976899] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: rockchip
Dec 30 20:45:03 icebox kernel: [ 1572.976902] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
Dec 30 20:45:03 icebox colord: Device added: sysfs-rockchip-rk30sdk
```

and `adb shell` then worked perfectly. You will notice the warning `bulk endpoint 0x81 has invalid maxpacket 64`. This means the Rockchip device is not compliant with the USB standards. My guess is that the Linux ehci-pci driver is more forgiving than the xhci_hcd driver.

Interestingly enough, I saw exactly the same behaviour on a Mac laptop, when I plugged in the Rockchip device. There, the kernel syslogged:

```
Dec 29 21:54:33 dhcp13 kernel[0]: USBF: 889121. 50      Endpoint 0x81 of the USB device "rk30sdk" at location 0x26400000:  converting Bulk MPS from 64 to 512 (USB 2.0 Spec section 5.8.3)
```

and `adb shell` broke in exactly the same way.

**TL;DR:**

Plugging into a USB2 port instead of a USB3 port might solve the issue.

Good luck!